# I want to create new variable with the help of existing variable

Tags: r, feature-engineering

I have data with variable name as "sales enquiry date", "sales enquiry stage"

i want to create a new variable "current stage date"

so example enquirer date is  10/03/2017 and stage is Meeting,
similarly, enquirer date is  27/04/2017 and stage is proposal.
i want new variable,
"Current stage date" <- if stage = meeting then enquirer date + 5 days
i.e 15/03/2017
similarly,
"current stage date" <- if stage = proposal then enquirer date + 10 days
i.e 07/05/2017

Comment: Please edit your question adding sample data with `dput`. Show example code and expected output.

Comment: How to produce a great R question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/8575672

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I second the commenters' recommendation for you to edit the question in line with the guidelines.

Assuming your data is in a data frame called `df` and the variable names are edited to not include spaces (good practice), is this what you need?

```
# tolower() to get around "Meeting"/"meeting"/"MEETING"...
df$current_stage_date <- if (tolower(df$sales_enquiry_stage) == "meeting") {
  df$sales_enquiry_date + 5
} else if (tolower(df$sales_enquiry_stage) == "proposal") df$sales_enquiry_date + 10
```

If there are only two possible values on `sales_enquiry_stage` (`meeting` and `proposal`), this can be further simplified to

```
df$current_stage_date <- df$sales_enquiry_date +
  ifelse(tolower(df$sales_enquiry_stage) == "meeting", 5, 10)
```

Comment: i tried but format getting changed, i.e, sales_enquiry_date <- 2018-07-01, after adding 5 value becomes 17718

Comment: Make sure the variables are of class `"Date"`. Look up working with dates in R if unsure what I'm talking about.